# Using lambda function compare values in a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Using `lambda` I want to write an module in which one function to return biggest of two numbers, another to return smallest of two numbers, another to return numbers are equal. Whenever you call the module, automatically it should ask two values to perform comparison.

I was able to do it in this way:

```
print('Input two values to compare')
a=[input(),input()]
big=lambda a: max(a)
small=lambda a: min(a)
equal=lambda a: a+['Both values are equal'] if(a[0]==a[1]) else 'Not equal'
big(a)
small(a)
equal(a)
```

This gives me correct output but the problem is I was unable to figure how to run this all simultaneously and print all three output, here only `equal(a)` function will execute but not `big(a)` and `small(a)` at a single flow.

I intend to execute all of this simultaneously when I call all of this in a module. Please do let me know if there is a better way of doing using `lambda`.

Comment: All of the lines will be executed. Do you mean to print the output of the three functions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "capture the output"?

Comment: I don't understand "capture the output at same instance" -  if you use `print( big(a), small(a), equal(a) )` then you see all values. If you run it in some strange way then it will show you only result from last function. But you can create `tuple` with all results putting all in one line `big(a), small(a), equal(a)` (separated by comma)

Comment: @jakub and martineau i meant to print the output of all the 3 functions at once.

Comment: @furas i have tried to use `print(big(a),small(a),equal(a))` but again it is printing only equal(a) result

Comment: "capture the output at same instance" i just wanted to mean to print all 3 outputs while i run, i dint say it better, i have edited my question .

Comment: how do you run it ? when I use `print(big(a),small(a),equal(a))` in module and import this module then I see all values.  I can't recreate your problem - so I can't see what is the problem and I can't help you. BTW: `input()` gives you alwasy string and you have to use `int()` or `float()` to convert to numbers. BTW: do you have other functions with name `big()`, `small()` or `max()`, `min()` ? Maybe you created functions with the same name but they don't return any value.

Comment: @furas i was testing it on juypter notebook i assumed that if that runs in a cell it should run in a module, but now i have all the code in module and trying this `print(big(a),small(a),equal(a))` this works perfectly fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem from the comments. Running the code in OP's post will return only the output of the last line, which is `equal(a)`. That is why OP sees only the output of `equal(a)`.

If you print the output of all three functions, you will see the output.

```
print('Input two values to compare')
a = [input(), input()]
big = lambda a: max(a)
small = lambda a: min(a)
equal = lambda a: a + ['Both values are equal'] if a[0] == a[1] else 'Not equal'
print(big(a), small(a), equal(a))
```

If you input `10` and `10`, this is the output:

```
Input two values to compare
10
10
10 10 ['10', '10', 'Both values are equal']
```

If you input `10` and `5`, this is the output:

```
Input two values to compare
10
5
5 10 Not equal
```

---

A few notes about your code.

- `input()` returns a string, so if you want a number, you will need to convert to `int` or `float`.
- the builtin functions `min` and `max` do exactly what `big` and `small` do. You could simply write `big = max` and `small = min`, but I would suggest using `min` and `max` directly instead of giving them another name.